# Why the TPS6104 can't output 27V voltage?

Tags: buck-boost

I bought a demo board of +- 12V voltage：
[image]

here is the schematic I drawed by the board:
[image]

I changed the 220k R1 to 500k potentiometer.
By the formula that gived in datasheet:
[image]

I expeted 27V voltage: , when the potentiomter is 500k, But it only give me 12.7V, and the voltage on  SW(pin 3) is not 1.233, but 0.627V.
I want to know the reason of I can't get 27V but 12.8V, and how to fix it?

With no output load, if the input voltage is 4V, when the output voltage is less than 15V, it's Ok, the input current is about 44mA; But after the output voltage is bigger than 18V, the input current suddenly rise to 240mA, and the output voltage becom 14V.

[Datasheet of TPS6104](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps61041.pdf?ts=1635694054611)

Comment: What is the load? And Vin is?

Comment: 1) That formula for \$V_{OUT}\$ applies to the typical application diagram, like figure 12 in the datasheet. Your schematic is **not** the same. If you remove C2 it might become similar enough though. 2) C2 "steals" some charge to make the negative output voltage, it might be that this limits the output voltage.

Comment: *the voltage on SW(pin 3) is not 1.233, but 0.627V* Realize that you will need to use an **oscilloscope** to properly measure the voltage at the SW pin as the SW pin switches between \$V_{IN}\$ and GND at high speed. Multimeters generally cannot deal with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, temporarily remove C2 and verify that V+ to GND is at desired 27V. If not, then the problem is with the potentiometer and possible long wires added. The feedback circuit cannot have noise which is easily picked up by a far away potentiometer. Replace the potentiometer with a real 500K SMD resistor and test again. If that works, then re-attach C2 and test the V+ to V- output again.

Understand that (1) the voltage on SW(pin3) is not a constant DC signal as Bimpelrekkie said, (2) the load current from the V- output will be more limited than V+ output.